# how to handle accessibility for web application when textbox label is not required to be shown

Tags: textbox, label, accessibility

In my web application I have textbox but I don't want to assign a label to it due to some specific purpose. But in order to provide accessibility it requires label to be associated with every textbox. In this case how to handle the accessibility without providing any label to textbox?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do `<input aria-label="my label here" />`. This way you won't have to have a label attribute/extra DOM node, but screen readers should still read out the aria-label text. Alternatively, you could use a `<label>` tag and just hide it with CSS.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. However at some places my label is hidden it wants: label should provide descriptive text.